# rviz is not publishing goal to the topic /move_base_simple/goal

Tags: navigation, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am setting up ros navigation stack on a robot that is not compatible with navigation stack out of the box. I am not using a static map for the navigation instead i have set the rolling_window parameters true for both global and local cost maps.
(I am not allowed to attach images so i will try my best to describe my situation in words.)

My rviz Screen shows the following objects

- local and global costmaps
- robot footprint.
- "2D Nav Goal" tool is pointing to /move_base_simple/goal.

`$ rostopic info /move_base_simple/goal`

Publishers:

- /rviz_1478194899883990323 (http://172.20.41.90:44168/)

Subscribers:

- /move_base (http://172.20.41.90:46055/)

`$ rostopic info /cmd_vel`

Publishers:

- /move_base (http://172.20.41.90:46055/)

Subscribers:

- /beam/beam (http://172.20.41.123:43113/)
- When I set a goal in rviz using "2D Nav Goal" tool, the terminal window of rviz shows the following information.

INFO [1478195397.235377567]: Setting goal: Frame:base_link, Position(0.558, -0.039, 0.000), Orientation(0.000, 0.000, 0.000, 1.000) = Angle: 0.000

In another terminal window i have following command running
"rostopic echo /move_base_simple/goal"

In another terminal window i have following command running
"rostopic echo /cmd_vel"

My problem is that when I set a goal in rviz screen i do not see anything published to /move_base_simple/goal or /cmd_vel topics.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247204/rviz-is-not-publishing-goal-to-the-topic-/move_base_simple/goal/) by [utkarshjp7](https://answers.ros.org/users/28161/utkarshjp7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2016-11-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shoemakerlevy9](https://answers.ros.org/users/27706/shoemakerlevy9/) on 2016-11-03**:
Are you running rviz on the same machine that rosmaster is running on?

**Comment by [utkarshjp7](https://answers.ros.org/users/28161/utkarshjp7/) on 2016-11-03**:
Yes. I was running rviz on a different machine. The problem was that on my rviz machine ROS_HOSTNAME parameter was pointing to the ip address of ros master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem was that on my local computer the parameter ROS_HOSTNAME was set to the ip address of the machine hosting ros master.

If anyone is having any trouble while running rviz on a machine different than the ros master, follow the instruction on this article:

[http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/~cteo/umd-erratic-ros-data/README-rvis-remote](http://www.umiacs.umd.edu/%7Ecteo/umd-erratic-ros-data/README-rvis-remote)

---

Originally posted by [utkarshjp7](https://answers.ros.org/users/28161/utkarshjp7/) with karma: 50 on 2016-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0